# How to add image in UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, image

i want to add image into `initWithActivityIndicatorStyle` instead of using the others like

`UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge`. So, when come to loading page, the image will act as

image loading.

Any help, i am truly appreciate it . ^^

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that. `UIActivityIndicatorView` draws the system activity indicators. If you want to display a custom image then you shouldn't be using a `UIActivityIndicatorView`. Either create a custom view, or if you just want to display an image use a `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` also supports animating several images in a loop if you want to do that.