# UIActivityIndicatorView PNG files

Tags: iphone

Where can I find the PNG files to the iPhone UIActivityIndicatorView animated indicator?

Comment: duplicate.. look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136050/how-to-add-image-in-uiactivityindicatorview

Comment: I don't want to have my own indicator animation.  I'm looking for the default PNG files to what UIActivityIndicatorView animates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [UIKit Artwork Extractor](http://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor). You'll find the files in `Shared/ProgressGear....png`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking in the Springboard.app. (Springboard is the home screen in iOS.) It should be located somewhere like:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app

The path will vary depending on the version of the SDK that you have installed.

I am away from my mac, so if you do find it there, please post a comment and I'll update my answer to add the specific information about where you found it.