# Add an image for UIActivityindicator in Objective-C

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I used this code in viewDidLoad,but the image is not shown before loading the image.

```
NSString *ImageString=@"http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg";

UIImage *HeartImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Heart.png"];

UIImageView *HeartImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:HeartImage];

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center=self.WebimageView.center;
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 30, 30);
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.WebimageView.frame.size.width /2, self.WebimageView.frame.size.height/2);
// [HeartImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
[self.WebimageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageString]
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


[self.WebimageView addSubview:activityIndicator];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add image in UIActivityIndicatorView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136050/how-to-add-image-in-uiactivityindicatorview)

Comment: Try to shift the code in ViewDidAppear() and try once again. May solve your issue..

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UIImage *heartImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Heart.png"];
UIImageView *heartImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:heartImage];

activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[heartImageView addSubview:activityIndicator];

[self.view addSubview:heartImageView];
```

edit: cleaned up

Comment: very good! you have to be careful with what you set the position to. I think you had a problem before because you set the position of activityIndicator wrong.

Comment: Thanks for giving this solution,but in mycase this is not working.

Comment: It's hard for me to know exactly whats wrong but check my update code in the answer please.

Comment: Parserk i was tried that is not working,you have to change,compare to before your code,is adding imageview to superview and then changing the frame also.

Comment: I've now tried this and it works. Please give more details and i can help you more.

Comment: I have to load the images dynamically by acheiving SDWebImage before loading the SDWebiamge is change the activity indicator image(Heart.png).This is only i want.

Comment: can't help you with that sorry