# How to Add image to uiactivityindicator view in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

This is my code that I have written in my project. Instead of a spinner I want to show an image.

```
progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:progress];
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136050/how-to-add-image-in-uiactivityindicatorview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171152/how-can-i-change-the-uiactivityindicatorview-to-set-a-custom-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved my issue long back , posting lately this is my answer it may helpful for other thats why i am posting here.

by using NVActivityIndicatorView i resolved my problem .NVActivityIndicatorView we can choose number of custom designs.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that as `UIActivityIndicatorView` is the system activity indicator. So if you want to do that then either you can create custom view for the same OR `UIImageView` supports animating several images in a loop(for, while) OR you can also add gif image for animation instead of `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

Comment: "UIImageView supports animating several images in a loop(for, while) " - actually, I don't think you can animate the frames manually. You call the methods `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your **`viewDidload()`** . **BuildingIcon_ImageView** is my `imageview` and when your image you want to load after set image hide `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

**Code :**

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 [indicator startAnimating];
 [indicator setCenter:BuildingIcon_ImageView.center];
 [BuildingIcon_ImageView addSubview:indicator];

BuildingIcon_ImageView.image=image;
[indicator removeFromSuperview];
```